# Google Now Stopped Working

Tags: launcher, google-now

Recently the Google Now Launcher stopped working. I had all the cards set up and working fine. Not sure why but Google now stopped working. I get an edit telling me " can't load search results" I also get No Internet connection.

I have a Galaxy S3 with 4.4 OS.

Can someone please help me get this problem resolved?

Thanking you in advance.

Frank

Comment: I am having the same problem

Comment: This problem appears to be fixed with the latest update to the "Google" app